# How to generate 3D mesh from CT Slices (.raw) using marching cubes algorithm in C#?

Tags: c#, raw-data, marching-cubes, medical-imaging, isosurface

I am trying to generate 3D mesh (isosurface extraction) from CT slices(.raw file) using the marching cubes algorithm.
The RAW data is 8 bits 512x512 px and 207 slices.
So the input is CT Raw data and the output is a 3D mesh of the CT Object
Can you pls help me? because I am stuck in this for more than 1 week
Can You please give me the programming Workflow to achieve that?

Next, the C# classes, which I converted from http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/

```
class TriTable
{
    public static int[,] LookupTable = new int[256,16] 
    {
        {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 8, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 1, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 8, 3, 9, 8, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 2, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 8, 3, 1, 2, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 2, 10, 0, 2, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {2, 8, 3, 2, 10, 8, 10, 9, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {3, 11, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 11, 2, 8, 11, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 9, 0, 2, 3, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 11, 2, 1, 9, 11, 9, 8, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {3, 10, 1, 11, 10, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 10, 1, 0, 8, 10, 8, 11, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {3, 9, 0, 3, 11, 9, 11, 10, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 8, 10, 10, 8, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {4, 7, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {4, 3, 0, 7, 3, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 1, 9, 8, 4, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {4, 1, 9, 4, 7, 1, 7, 3, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 2, 10, 8, 4, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {3, 4, 7, 3, 0, 4, 1, 2, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 2, 10, 9, 0, 2, 8, 4, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {2, 10, 9, 2, 9, 7, 2, 7, 3, 7, 9, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {8, 4, 7, 3, 11, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {11, 4, 7, 11, 2, 4, 2, 0, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 0, 1, 8, 4, 7, 2, 3, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {4, 7, 11, 9, 4, 11, 9, 11, 2, 9, 2, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {3, 10, 1, 3, 11, 10, 7, 8, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 11, 10, 1, 4, 11, 1, 0, 4, 7, 11, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 11, 9, 11, 10, 11, 0, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {4, 7, 11, 4, 11, 9, 9, 11, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 5, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 5, 4, 0, 8, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 5, 4, 1, 5, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {8, 5, 4, 8, 3, 5, 3, 1, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 2, 10, 9, 5, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {3, 0, 8, 1, 2, 10, 4, 9, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {5, 2, 10, 5, 4, 2, 4, 0, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {2, 10, 5, 3, 2, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 5, 4, 2, 3, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 11, 2, 0, 8, 11, 4, 9, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 5, 4, 0, 1, 5, 2, 3, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {2, 1, 5, 2, 5, 8, 2, 8, 11, 4, 8, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {10, 3, 11, 10, 1, 3, 9, 5, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {4, 9, 5, 0, 8, 1, 8, 10, 1, 8, 11, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {5, 4, 0, 5, 0, 11, 5, 11, 10, 11, 0, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {5, 4, 8, 5, 8, 10, 10, 8, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 7, 8, 5, 7, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 3, 0, 9, 5, 3, 5, 7, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 7, 8, 0, 1, 7, 1, 5, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 5, 3, 3, 5, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 7, 8, 9, 5, 7, 10, 1, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {10, 1, 2, 9, 5, 0, 5, 3, 0, 5, 7, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {8, 0, 2, 8, 2, 5, 8, 5, 7, 10, 5, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {2, 10, 5, 2, 5, 3, 3, 5, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {7, 9, 5, 7, 8, 9, 3, 11, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 5, 7, 9, 7, 2, 9, 2, 0, 2, 7, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {2, 3, 11, 0, 1, 8, 1, 7, 8, 1, 5, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {11, 2, 1, 11, 1, 7, 7, 1, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 5, 8, 8, 5, 7, 10, 1, 3, 10, 3, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {5, 7, 0, 5, 0, 9, 7, 11, 0, 1, 0, 10, 11, 10, 0, -1},
        {11, 10, 0, 11, 0, 3, 10, 5, 0, 8, 0, 7, 5, 7, 0, -1},
        {11, 10, 5, 7, 11, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {10, 6, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 8, 3, 5, 10, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 0, 1, 5, 10, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 8, 3, 1, 9, 8, 5, 10, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 6, 5, 2, 6, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 6, 5, 1, 2, 6, 3, 0, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 6, 5, 9, 0, 6, 0, 2, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {5, 9, 8, 5, 8, 2, 5, 2, 6, 3, 2, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {2, 3, 11, 10, 6, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {11, 0, 8, 11, 2, 0, 10, 6, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 1, 9, 2, 3, 11, 5, 10, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {5, 10, 6, 1, 9, 2, 9, 11, 2, 9, 8, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {6, 3, 11, 6, 5, 3, 5, 1, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 8, 11, 0, 11, 5, 0, 5, 1, 5, 11, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {3, 11, 6, 0, 3, 6, 0, 6, 5, 0, 5, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {6, 5, 9, 6, 9, 11, 11, 9, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {5, 10, 6, 4, 7, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {4, 3, 0, 4, 7, 3, 6, 5, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 9, 0, 5, 10, 6, 8, 4, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {10, 6, 5, 1, 9, 7, 1, 7, 3, 7, 9, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {6, 1, 2, 6, 5, 1, 4, 7, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 2, 5, 5, 2, 6, 3, 0, 4, 3, 4, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {8, 4, 7, 9, 0, 5, 0, 6, 5, 0, 2, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {7, 3, 9, 7, 9, 4, 3, 2, 9, 5, 9, 6, 2, 6, 9, -1},
        {3, 11, 2, 7, 8, 4, 10, 6, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {5, 10, 6, 4, 7, 2, 4, 2, 0, 2, 7, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 1, 9, 4, 7, 8, 2, 3, 11, 5, 10, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 2, 1, 9, 11, 2, 9, 4, 11, 7, 11, 4, 5, 10, 6, -1},
        {8, 4, 7, 3, 11, 5, 3, 5, 1, 5, 11, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {5, 1, 11, 5, 11, 6, 1, 0, 11, 7, 11, 4, 0, 4, 11, -1},
        {0, 5, 9, 0, 6, 5, 0, 3, 6, 11, 6, 3, 8, 4, 7, -1},
        {6, 5, 9, 6, 9, 11, 4, 7, 9, 7, 11, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {10, 4, 9, 6, 4, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {4, 10, 6, 4, 9, 10, 0, 8, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {10, 0, 1, 10, 6, 0, 6, 4, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {8, 3, 1, 8, 1, 6, 8, 6, 4, 6, 1, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 4, 9, 1, 2, 4, 2, 6, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {3, 0, 8, 1, 2, 9, 2, 4, 9, 2, 6, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 2, 4, 4, 2, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {8, 3, 2, 8, 2, 4, 4, 2, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {10, 4, 9, 10, 6, 4, 11, 2, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 8, 2, 2, 8, 11, 4, 9, 10, 4, 10, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {3, 11, 2, 0, 1, 6, 0, 6, 4, 6, 1, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {6, 4, 1, 6, 1, 10, 4, 8, 1, 2, 1, 11, 8, 11, 1, -1},
        {9, 6, 4, 9, 3, 6, 9, 1, 3, 11, 6, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {8, 11, 1, 8, 1, 0, 11, 6, 1, 9, 1, 4, 6, 4, 1, -1},
        {3, 11, 6, 3, 6, 0, 0, 6, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {6, 4, 8, 11, 6, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {7, 10, 6, 7, 8, 10, 8, 9, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 7, 3, 0, 10, 7, 0, 9, 10, 6, 7, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {10, 6, 7, 1, 10, 7, 1, 7, 8, 1, 8, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {10, 6, 7, 10, 7, 1, 1, 7, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 2, 6, 1, 6, 8, 1, 8, 9, 8, 6, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {2, 6, 9, 2, 9, 1, 6, 7, 9, 0, 9, 3, 7, 3, 9, -1},
        {7, 8, 0, 7, 0, 6, 6, 0, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {7, 3, 2, 6, 7, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {2, 3, 11, 10, 6, 8, 10, 8, 9, 8, 6, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {2, 0, 7, 2, 7, 11, 0, 9, 7, 6, 7, 10, 9, 10, 7, -1},
        {1, 8, 0, 1, 7, 8, 1, 10, 7, 6, 7, 10, 2, 3, 11, -1},
        {11, 2, 1, 11, 1, 7, 10, 6, 1, 6, 7, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {8, 9, 6, 8, 6, 7, 9, 1, 6, 11, 6, 3, 1, 3, 6, -1},
        {0, 9, 1, 11, 6, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {7, 8, 0, 7, 0, 6, 3, 11, 0, 11, 6, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {7, 11, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {7, 6, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {3, 0, 8, 11, 7, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 1, 9, 11, 7, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {8, 1, 9, 8, 3, 1, 11, 7, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {10, 1, 2, 6, 11, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 2, 10, 3, 0, 8, 6, 11, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {2, 9, 0, 2, 10, 9, 6, 11, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {6, 11, 7, 2, 10, 3, 10, 8, 3, 10, 9, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {7, 2, 3, 6, 2, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {7, 0, 8, 7, 6, 0, 6, 2, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {2, 7, 6, 2, 3, 7, 0, 1, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 6, 2, 1, 8, 6, 1, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {10, 7, 6, 10, 1, 7, 1, 3, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {10, 7, 6, 1, 7, 10, 1, 8, 7, 1, 0, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 3, 7, 0, 7, 10, 0, 10, 9, 6, 10, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {7, 6, 10, 7, 10, 8, 8, 10, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {6, 8, 4, 11, 8, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {3, 6, 11, 3, 0, 6, 0, 4, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {8, 6, 11, 8, 4, 6, 9, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 4, 6, 9, 6, 3, 9, 3, 1, 11, 3, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {6, 8, 4, 6, 11, 8, 2, 10, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 2, 10, 3, 0, 11, 0, 6, 11, 0, 4, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {4, 11, 8, 4, 6, 11, 0, 2, 9, 2, 10, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {10, 9, 3, 10, 3, 2, 9, 4, 3, 11, 3, 6, 4, 6, 3, -1},
        {8, 2, 3, 8, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 9, 0, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6, 4, 3, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 9, 4, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {8, 1, 3, 8, 6, 1, 8, 4, 6, 6, 10, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {10, 1, 0, 10, 0, 6, 6, 0, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {4, 6, 3, 4, 3, 8, 6, 10, 3, 0, 3, 9, 10, 9, 3, -1},
        {10, 9, 4, 6, 10, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {4, 9, 5, 7, 6, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 8, 3, 4, 9, 5, 11, 7, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {5, 0, 1, 5, 4, 0, 7, 6, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {11, 7, 6, 8, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 5, 4, 10, 1, 2, 7, 6, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {6, 11, 7, 1, 2, 10, 0, 8, 3, 4, 9, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {7, 6, 11, 5, 4, 10, 4, 2, 10, 4, 0, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {3, 4, 8, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 5, 10, 5, 2, 11, 7, 6, -1},
        {7, 2, 3, 7, 6, 2, 5, 4, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 5, 4, 0, 8, 6, 0, 6, 2, 6, 8, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {3, 6, 2, 3, 7, 6, 1, 5, 0, 5, 4, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {6, 2, 8, 6, 8, 7, 2, 1, 8, 4, 8, 5, 1, 5, 8, -1},
        {9, 5, 4, 10, 1, 6, 1, 7, 6, 1, 3, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 6, 10, 1, 7, 6, 1, 0, 7, 8, 7, 0, 9, 5, 4, -1},
        {4, 0, 10, 4, 10, 5, 0, 3, 10, 6, 10, 7, 3, 7, 10, -1},
        {7, 6, 10, 7, 10, 8, 5, 4, 10, 4, 8, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {6, 9, 5, 6, 11, 9, 11, 8, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {3, 6, 11, 0, 6, 3, 0, 5, 6, 0, 9, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 11, 8, 0, 5, 11, 0, 1, 5, 5, 6, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {6, 11, 3, 6, 3, 5, 5, 3, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 2, 10, 9, 5, 11, 9, 11, 8, 11, 5, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 11, 3, 0, 6, 11, 0, 9, 6, 5, 6, 9, 1, 2, 10, -1},
        {11, 8, 5, 11, 5, 6, 8, 0, 5, 10, 5, 2, 0, 2, 5, -1},
        {6, 11, 3, 6, 3, 5, 2, 10, 3, 10, 5, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {5, 8, 9, 5, 2, 8, 5, 6, 2, 3, 8, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 5, 6, 9, 6, 0, 0, 6, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 5, 8, 1, 8, 0, 5, 6, 8, 3, 8, 2, 6, 2, 8, -1},
        {1, 5, 6, 2, 1, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 3, 6, 1, 6, 10, 3, 8, 6, 5, 6, 9, 8, 9, 6, -1},
        {10, 1, 0, 10, 0, 6, 9, 5, 0, 5, 6, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 3, 8, 5, 6, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {10, 5, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {11, 5, 10, 7, 5, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {11, 5, 10, 11, 7, 5, 8, 3, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {5, 11, 7, 5, 10, 11, 1, 9, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {10, 7, 5, 10, 11, 7, 9, 8, 1, 8, 3, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {11, 1, 2, 11, 7, 1, 7, 5, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 8, 3, 1, 2, 7, 1, 7, 5, 7, 2, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 7, 5, 9, 2, 7, 9, 0, 2, 2, 11, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {7, 5, 2, 7, 2, 11, 5, 9, 2, 3, 2, 8, 9, 8, 2, -1},
        {2, 5, 10, 2, 3, 5, 3, 7, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {8, 2, 0, 8, 5, 2, 8, 7, 5, 10, 2, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 0, 1, 5, 10, 3, 5, 3, 7, 3, 10, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 8, 2, 9, 2, 1, 8, 7, 2, 10, 2, 5, 7, 5, 2, -1},
        {1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 8, 7, 0, 7, 1, 1, 7, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 0, 3, 9, 3, 5, 5, 3, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 8, 7, 5, 9, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {5, 8, 4, 5, 10, 8, 10, 11, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {5, 0, 4, 5, 11, 0, 5, 10, 11, 11, 3, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 1, 9, 8, 4, 10, 8, 10, 11, 10, 4, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {10, 11, 4, 10, 4, 5, 11, 3, 4, 9, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4, -1},
        {2, 5, 1, 2, 8, 5, 2, 11, 8, 4, 5, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 4, 11, 0, 11, 3, 4, 5, 11, 2, 11, 1, 5, 1, 11, -1},
        {0, 2, 5, 0, 5, 9, 2, 11, 5, 4, 5, 8, 11, 8, 5, -1},
        {9, 4, 5, 2, 11, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {2, 5, 10, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 8, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {5, 10, 2, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {3, 10, 2, 3, 5, 10, 3, 8, 5, 4, 5, 8, 0, 1, 9, -1},
        {5, 10, 2, 5, 2, 4, 1, 9, 2, 9, 4, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {8, 4, 5, 8, 5, 3, 3, 5, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 4, 5, 1, 0, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {8, 4, 5, 8, 5, 3, 9, 0, 5, 0, 3, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 4, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {4, 11, 7, 4, 9, 11, 9, 10, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 8, 3, 4, 9, 7, 9, 11, 7, 9, 10, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 10, 11, 1, 11, 4, 1, 4, 0, 7, 4, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {3, 1, 4, 3, 4, 8, 1, 10, 4, 7, 4, 11, 10, 11, 4, -1},
        {4, 11, 7, 9, 11, 4, 9, 2, 11, 9, 1, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 7, 4, 9, 11, 7, 9, 1, 11, 2, 11, 1, 0, 8, 3, -1},
        {11, 7, 4, 11, 4, 2, 2, 4, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {11, 7, 4, 11, 4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {2, 9, 10, 2, 7, 9, 2, 3, 7, 7, 4, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 10, 7, 9, 7, 4, 10, 2, 7, 8, 7, 0, 2, 0, 7, -1},
        {3, 7, 10, 3, 10, 2, 7, 4, 10, 1, 10, 0, 4, 0, 10, -1},
        {1, 10, 2, 8, 7, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {4, 9, 1, 4, 1, 7, 7, 1, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {4, 9, 1, 4, 1, 7, 0, 8, 1, 8, 7, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {4, 0, 3, 7, 4, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {4, 8, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 10, 8, 10, 11, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {3, 0, 9, 3, 9, 11, 11, 9, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 1, 10, 0, 10, 8, 8, 10, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {3, 1, 10, 11, 3, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 2, 11, 1, 11, 9, 9, 11, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {3, 0, 9, 3, 9, 11, 1, 2, 9, 2, 11, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 2, 11, 8, 0, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {3, 2, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {2, 3, 8, 2, 8, 10, 10, 8, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {9, 10, 2, 0, 9, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {2, 3, 8, 2, 8, 10, 0, 1, 8, 1, 10, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 10, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {1, 3, 8, 9, 1, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 9, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, 3, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
        {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}
    };
}
```

}

```
public class Triangle
{
    public Point3D[] p = new Point3D[3];
}

public class GridCell
{
    public Point3D[] p = new Point3D[8];
    public Int32[] val = new Int32[8];

    // Creates a new GridCell for adjacent CT Slices.
    // For the index convention, please refer to the article 'Polygonising a scalar field' written by Paul Bourke.
    // http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/

    public GridCell(int theSliceIndex, int theRowIndex, int theColumnIndex, CTSliceInfo CTSliceFront, CTSliceInfo CTSliceBack)
    {
        double X_Left_Front = CTSliceFront.UpperLeft_X + (theColumnIndex * CTSliceFront.PixelSpacing_X);
        double X_Right_Front = X_Left_Front + CTSliceFront.PixelSpacing_X;

        double X_Left_Back = CTSliceBack.UpperLeft_X + (theColumnIndex * CTSliceBack.PixelSpacing_X);
        double X_Right_Back = X_Left_Back + CTSliceBack.PixelSpacing_X;

        double Y_Top_Front = CTSliceFront.UpperLeft_Y + (theRowIndex * CTSliceFront.PixelSpacing_Y);
        double Y_Botton_Front = Y_Top_Front + CTSliceFront.PixelSpacing_Y;

        double Y_Top_Back = CTSliceBack.UpperLeft_Y + (theRowIndex * CTSliceBack.PixelSpacing_Y);
        double Y_Botton_Back = Y_Top_Back + CTSliceBack.PixelSpacing_Y;

        double Z_Front = CTSliceFront.UpperLeft_Z;
        double Z_Back = CTSliceBack.UpperLeft_Z;

        p[0] = new Point3D( X_Left_Back,   Y_Botton_Back ,  Z_Back);
        p[1] = new Point3D( X_Right_Back,  Y_Botton_Back ,  Z_Back);
        p[2] = new Point3D( X_Right_Front, Y_Botton_Front , Z_Front);
        p[3] = new Point3D( X_Left_Front,  Y_Botton_Front , Z_Front);
        p[4] = new Point3D( X_Left_Back,   Y_Top_Back ,     Z_Back);
        p[5] = new Point3D( X_Right_Back,  Y_Top_Back ,     Z_Back);
        p[6] = new Point3D( X_Right_Front, Y_Top_Front ,    Z_Front);
        p[7] = new Point3D( X_Left_Front,  Y_Top_Front ,    Z_Front);

        val[0] = CTSliceBack.GetHounsfieldPixelValue(theRowIndex + 1, theColumnIndex);
        val[1] = CTSliceBack.GetHounsfieldPixelValue(theRowIndex + 1, theColumnIndex + 1);
        val[2] = CTSliceFront.GetHounsfieldPixelValue(theRowIndex + 1, theColumnIndex + 1);
        val[3] = CTSliceFront.GetHounsfieldPixelValue(theRowIndex + 1, theColumnIndex);
        val[4] = CTSliceBack.GetHounsfieldPixelValue(theRowIndex, theColumnIndex);
        val[5] = CTSliceBack.GetHounsfieldPixelValue(theRowIndex, theColumnIndex + 1);
        val[6] = CTSliceFront.GetHounsfieldPixelValue(theRowIndex, theColumnIndex + 1);
        val[7] = CTSliceFront.GetHounsfieldPixelValue(theRowIndex, theColumnIndex);
    }
}



class MarchingCubes
{
    // Given a grid cell and an isolevel, calculate the triangular facets required to represent the isosurface through the cell.
    // Return the number of triangular facets, the array "triangles" will be loaded up with the vertices at most 5 triangular facets.
    // 0 will be returned if the grid cell is either totally above of totally below the isolevel.
    public static void Polygonise(GridCell grid, double isolevel, ref List<Triangle> theTriangleList)
    {
        // Determine the index into the edge table which tells us which vertices are inside of the surface
        int cubeindex = 0;
        if (grid.val[0] < isolevel) cubeindex |= 1;
        if (grid.val[1] < isolevel) cubeindex |= 2;
        if (grid.val[2] < isolevel) cubeindex |= 4;
        if (grid.val[3] < isolevel) cubeindex |= 8;
        if (grid.val[4] < isolevel) cubeindex |= 16;
        if (grid.val[5] < isolevel) cubeindex |= 32;
        if (grid.val[6] < isolevel) cubeindex |= 64;
        if (grid.val[7] < isolevel) cubeindex |= 128;

        // Cube is entirely in/out of the surface 
        if (EdgeTable.LookupTable[cubeindex] == 0)
            return;

        Point3D[] vertlist = new Point3D[12];

        // Find the vertices where the surface intersects the cube 
        if ((EdgeTable.LookupTable[cubeindex] & 1) > 0)
            vertlist[0] = VertexInterp(isolevel, grid.p[0], grid.p[1], grid.val[0], grid.val[1]);

        if ((EdgeTable.LookupTable[cubeindex] & 2) > 0)
            vertlist[1] = VertexInterp(isolevel, grid.p[1], grid.p[2], grid.val[1], grid.val[2]);

        if ((EdgeTable.LookupTable[cubeindex] & 4) > 0)
            vertlist[2] = VertexInterp(isolevel, grid.p[2], grid.p[3], grid.val[2], grid.val[3]);

        if ((EdgeTable.LookupTable[cubeindex] & 8) > 0)
            vertlist[3] = VertexInterp(isolevel, grid.p[3], grid.p[0], grid.val[3], grid.val[0]);

        if ((EdgeTable.LookupTable[cubeindex] & 16) > 0)
            vertlist[4] = VertexInterp(isolevel, grid.p[4], grid.p[5], grid.val[4], grid.val[5]);

        if ((EdgeTable.LookupTable[cubeindex] & 32) > 0)
            vertlist[5] = VertexInterp(isolevel, grid.p[5], grid.p[6], grid.val[5], grid.val[6]);

        if ((EdgeTable.LookupTable[cubeindex] & 64) > 0)
            vertlist[6] = VertexInterp(isolevel, grid.p[6], grid.p[7], grid.val[6], grid.val[7]);

        if ((EdgeTable.LookupTable[cubeindex] & 128) > 0)
            vertlist[7] = VertexInterp(isolevel, grid.p[7], grid.p[4], grid.val[7], grid.val[4]);

        if ((EdgeTable.LookupTable[cubeindex] & 256) > 0)
            vertlist[8] = VertexInterp(isolevel, grid.p[0], grid.p[4], grid.val[0], grid.val[4]);

        if ((EdgeTable.LookupTable[cubeindex] & 512) > 0)
            vertlist[9] = VertexInterp(isolevel, grid.p[1], grid.p[5], grid.val[1], grid.val[5]);

        if ((EdgeTable.LookupTable[cubeindex] & 1024) > 0)
            vertlist[10] = VertexInterp(isolevel, grid.p[2], grid.p[6], grid.val[2], grid.val[6]);

        if ((EdgeTable.LookupTable[cubeindex] & 2048) > 0)
            vertlist[11] = VertexInterp(isolevel, grid.p[3], grid.p[7], grid.val[3], grid.val[7]);

        // Create the triangle 
        for (int i = 0; TriTable.LookupTable[cubeindex, i] != -1; i += 3)
        {
            Triangle aTriangle = new Triangle();

            aTriangle.p[0] = vertlist[TriTable.LookupTable[cubeindex, i]];
            aTriangle.p[1] = vertlist[TriTable.LookupTable[cubeindex, i + 1]];
            aTriangle.p[2] = vertlist[TriTable.LookupTable[cubeindex, i + 2]];

            theTriangleList.Add(aTriangle);
        }
    }

    public static Point3D VertexInterp(double isolevel, Point3D p1, Point3D p2, double valp1, double valp2)
    {
        double mu;
        Point3D p = new Point3D();

        if (Math.Abs(isolevel-valp1) < 0.00001)
            return(p1);

        if (Math.Abs(isolevel-valp2) < 0.00001)
            return(p2);

        if (Math.Abs(valp1-valp2) < 0.00001)
            return(p1);

        mu = (isolevel - valp1) / (valp2 - valp1);
        
        p.X = p1.X + mu * (p2.X - p1.X);
        p.Y = p1.Y + mu * (p2.Y - p1.Y);
        p.Z = p1.Z + mu * (p2.Z - p1.Z);

        return(p);
    }
}
```

}

```
    private void DisplayImage08(string fileName)
    {
        // Open a binary reader to read in the pixel data. 
        // We cannot use the usual image loading mechanisms since this   is raw 
                
        try
        {
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open));
            byte pixByte;
            int iTotalSize = (int)br.BaseStream.Length;

            canvas.Width = width;
            canvas.Height = height;
            img.Width = width;
            img.Height = height;
            pix08 = new byte[iTotalSize];

            for (int i = 0; i < iTotalSize; ++i)
            {
                pixByte = (byte)(br.ReadByte());
                pix08[i] = pixByte;
            }
            br.Close();

            int bitsPerPixel = 8;
            stride = (width * bitsPerPixel) / 8;

            // Schleife über das komplette Array mit 207 Schichten
            var singleImage = new byte[512 * 512];
            
            var counter = 0;
            var singleImageIndex = 0;
            for ( int i = 0; i < iTotalSize; i++)
            {
                if(singleImageIndex == 512*512 - 1)
                {
                    // bitmap erstellen nachdem eine Schicht gelesen ist
                    arrayBitmap[counter] = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Gray8, null, singleImage, stride);
                    counter++;
                    singleImageIndex = 0;
                }

                singleImage[singleImageIndex] = pix08[i];
                singleImageIndex++;
            }

            // Beispiel code um die Schicht 111 anzuzeigen
            img.Source = arrayBitmap[127];  
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error");
        }
    }
```

The Problem Now is, how to work with the input CT data (.raw file)??
I have no idea how to prepare the data, that I can apply the marching cubes algorithm to it. This is my first time working with such a data type.
I really appreciate your help!

Comment: So is your main question how to read data from a text/binary file? If so then it seems  that the code you have posted is not really relevant for your problem.

Comment: Yes, exactly but the code is the main part. I have a huge problem with how to read the RAW CT data (8 bits 512X512 px 207 slices)?  I have created a Class CTSliceInfo.cs, but I have no idea what I should write in it?

Comment: I see. I would suggest that you post the specifications of the file format you mentioned and some test data. I am happy to help you figure this out then. At the moment, I am not sure what CT data file (.raw) actually refers to. Are there different file formats used by different CT vendors? Is there a standard definition of this raw file format? Not sure

Comment: Thank you @MouseOnMars. The raw data is about 207 slices taken from a CT machine. The CT images are thresholded in 8 bits with 512 X 512 pixels.
A raw image file is one that has just the pixel data arranged in a top-down, left-to-right manner. It does not have any header.
Hier same test data https://github.com/Dhaour9x/RAW-Database

Answer (score 0):

This code reads the data one row at a time. The list contains a collection of 2D byte arrays. Each array stores 512 by 512 8 bit values.

```
private static List<byte[,]> GetCTSlices(string path)
{
    const int size = 512;
    List<byte[,]> data = new List<byte[,]>();

    try
    {
        using (FileStream fsSource = new FileStream(path,
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {

            byte[] bytes = new byte[fsSource.Length];

            int n = fsSource.Read(bytes, 0, (int)fsSource.Length);

            data = ConvertToByteArray2D(bytes, size);
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ioEx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ioEx.Message);
    }
    return data;
}

private static List<byte[,]> ConvertToByteArray2D(byte[] bytes, int size)
{
    var data = new List<byte[,]>();
    int imageSize = size * size;


    int s = 0;
    while (bytes.Length - s*imageSize > 0)
    {
        var byteArray2D = new byte[size, size];

        for (int i = s*imageSize; i < (s+1)*imageSize; i++)
        {
            int row = (i % imageSize) / size;
            int col = (i % imageSize ) - row * size;
            byteArray2D[row, col] = bytes[i];
        }
        s++;
        data.Add(byteArray2D);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but why did you declare size with 256 and Do you mean by this (int imageSize = size * size;) the resolution of input data.my raw data is 512x512x207 8 bit (Voxels).

Comment: My bad, you are right size should equal 512. imageSize defines how many pixels are in one slice if I adopt your terminology. When executed ConvertToByteArray2D should return a list with 207 items, each item being a 512x512 byte array. Hope that helps

Comment: I have update my question with Function ***DisplayImage08***. How can I calculate and return pixel values from an gray8 image? I have to fill in the following function `public int GetPixelValue(BitmapSource image, int row, int column)
        {
            int pixelValue = 0;

            // Hier Pixel Wert berechnen und zurückgeben.

            return pixelValue; 
        }
    }`

Comment: Please ask a new question and strip the code down to the minimum required. Please clarify what works what doesn't and where you need help. I just see a large method that somehow tries to manipulate img which is not defined